Approach beacons location
What is the characteristic of the 2x "approach beacons" mention in the Singapore's AIP Runway 02L. (Picture attached below ). I cant find anything in the ICAO Annex 14 that describe the location of this beacon to be placed with the CAT II Approaching Light System on a runway.


A search for "approach beacon" in ICAO and CASA of Singapore online documentation doesn't yield any result, except CASA AIP entries like the one you show in the question. So it's indeed a mystery. I'm proposing three possible explanations.
1: "Approach beacons" refers to airport beacons
There are indeed two airport identification beacons at WSSS:

Source: Jepessen, via virtualairlines.eu
2: Additional lights in the approach path
These two black squares on the right of the ALSF-2 drawing:



Source: Jepessen, via virtualairlines.eu
I don't know what they represent, and wasn't able to find a an explanation in the Jepessen legend. ICAO prohibits a light at this position when the ALS is active. From ICAO Annex 14:

5.3.4.29: b) no light other than a light located within the central part of a crossbar or a centre line barrette (not their extremities) shall be screened from an approaching aircraft.

But the AIP doesn't state these beacons are part of the standard precision approach. These two beacons must be external to the ALSF-2 standard, and wouldn't be used when ALSF-2 is operational.
3: Additional lights in the approach path
The lightning system is an ALSF-2, implementing ICAO standard for the lightning  of a Cat II/III precision approach:



Source: ICAO Annex 14, via Switzerland FOCA
But on an aerial view, there is an additional mast with two lights in the stopway, on the centerline:



Source Google Maps
In some drawings for ALSF-2 there are two beacons at about 50m (150ft) from the threshold, between the centerline and the side row lights, never described. This one is from FAA:



Source: FAA
While the position isn't exactly the same, this additional mast can be for the additional lights, again not used when the ALSF-2 is active.

+1 for a solid research effort despite not giving a definitive answer
